# TSP for Complete Directed Graph

Tags: graph, traveling-salesman

Does there exist a polynomial time algorithm for Travelling Salesman Problem on complete directed graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlikely. If there was one you could take any graph and add all the missing edges with a very high weight. That would allow solving the standard version of the problem, which is known to be NP-hard.